# Flutter Cloud_Firestore and Google ml kit not working together

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-dependencies, google-mlkit

`[Terminal Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ph9G.png)

V/NativeCrypto(25754): Registering com/google/android/gms/org/conscrypt/NativeCrypto's 305 native methods...
W/olour_blindness(25754): Accessing hidden method Ljava/security/spec/ECParameterSpec;->getCurveName()Ljava/lang/String; (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
I/ProviderInstaller(25754): Installed default security provider GmsCore_OpenSSL
D/FirebaseAuth(25754): Notifying id token listeners about user ( iFFYCAgC80X6el3dxomADCSP43w1 ).
D/TrafficStats(25754): tagSocket(165) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
W/olour_blindness(25754): Accessing hidden field Ljava/net/Socket;->impl:Ljava/net/SocketImpl; (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
W/olour_blindness(25754): Accessing hidden method Ljava/security/spec/ECParameterSpec;->setCurveName(Ljava/lang/String;)V (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
D/TrafficStats(25754): tagSocket(167) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
W/Firestore(25754): (24.10.3) [WatchStream]: (7c1cc0a) Stream closed with status: Status{code=INTERNAL, description=error in frame handler, cause=java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No interface method getBuffer()Lokio/Buffer; in class Lokio/BufferedSource; or its super classes (declaration of 'okio.BufferedSource' appears in /data/app/~~Brcb4mjgO_qiFDBE_URIPA==/com.example.colour_blindness-iY1vV5zCd1xxARNjCusEgg==/base.apk!classes21.dex)
W/Firestore(25754):     at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpClientTransport$ClientFrameHandler.data(OkHttpClientTransport.java:1146)
W/Firestore(25754):     at io.grpc.okhttp.internal.framed.Http2$Reader.readData(Http2.java:236)
W/Firestore(25754):     at io.grpc.okhttp.internal.framed.Http2$Reader.nextFrame(Http2.java:148)
W/Firestore(25754):     at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpClientTransport$ClientFrameHandler.run(OkHttpClientTransport.java:1105)
W/Firestore(25754):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
W/Firestore(25754):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644)
W/Firestore(25754):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
W/Firestore(25754): }.
W/Firestore(25754): (24.10.3) [OnlineStateTracker]: Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Connection failed 1 times. Most recent error: Status{code=INTERNAL, description=error in frame handler, cause=java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No interface method getBuffer()Lokio/Buffer; in class Lokio/BufferedSource; or its super classes (declaration of 'okio.BufferedSource' appears in /data/app/~~Brcb4mjgO_qiFDBE_URIPA==/com.example.colour_blindness-iY1vV5zCd1xxARNjCusEgg==/base.apk!classes21.dex)
W/Firestore(25754):     at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpClientTransport$ClientFrameHandler.data(OkHttpClientTransport.java:1146)
W/Firestore(25754):     at io.grpc.okhttp.internal.framed.Http2$Reader.readData(Http2.java:236)
W/Firestore(25754):     at io.grpc.okhttp.internal.framed.Http2$Reader.nextFrame(Http2.java:148)
W/Firestore(25754):     at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpClientTransport$ClientFrameHandler.run(OkHttpClientTransport.java:1105)
W/Firestore(25754):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
W/Firestore(25754):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644)
W/Firestore(25754):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
W/Firestore(25754): }
W/Firestore(25754): This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.
I/flutter (25754): Error loading profile data: [cloud_firestore/unavailable] The service is currently unavailable. This is a most likely a transient condition and may be corrected by retrying with a backoff.

══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following LateError was thrown building ProfileScreen(dirty, state: _ProfileScreenState#74c6a):
LateInitializationError: Field '_name@1309061384' has not been initialized.
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      _ProfileScreenState._name (package:colour_blindness/profile_screen.dart)
#1      _ProfileScreenState._buildProfileForm (package:colour_blindness/profile_screen.dart:82:29)
#2      _ProfileScreenState.build (package:colour_blindness/profile_screen.dart:68:22)
#3      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5592:27)
#4      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5480:15)
#5      StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5643:11)
#6      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5196:7)
#7      BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2904:19)
#8      WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:989:21)
#9      RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:448:5)
#10     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1386:15)
#11     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1311:9)
#12     SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1169:5)
#13     _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:312:13)
#14     PlatformDispatcher._drawFrame (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:399:5)
#15     _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:283:31)`